# Remove Simplenews Newsletters?

Tags: 7, emails

I had set a content type to allow it to be used as a simplenews newsletter, and then updated the JSON Feeds Processor so that it filled in the simplenews category for all the items.

However after realizing this wasn't what I needed, I removed the field simplenews from the content type and removed the option "use as newsletter" too, but all the newsletters still show up in the admin page.

I want to delete all of these old newsletters but there doesn't seem to be any option in the module to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to remove Simple newsletter completely. You need to disable and uninstall the module.

Follow the steps

1. Go to Modules list (`admin/modules`) and uncheck simplenews letter to disable and click 'Save Configuration' to disable the module
2. Then Go to `admin/modules/uninstall` page and select/check the simplenews letter module and click 'Uninstall' to remove all data related to Simplenews letter module from your instance.

Comment: So you're saying I need to uninstall the module just to clear the newsletters and then re-install it again ?

I already have a newsletter that is setup to be sent weekly which I want to keep. I just need to remove the "older" newsletters that were made for each content type

Comment: @dan2k3k4 oh ok, then don't unistall. First try 'clear cache' and check. did you do that?

Comment: Cache is the first thing I cleared (drush as well as from the site admin) and it still shows the news letters... I guess I need to connect to the DB and delete them as simplenews doesn't seem to have anything :/

Comment: @dan2k3k4 It seems the module bug. :-|  I suggest you to take a db backup before proceeding. you might aware of that  :)

Answer (score 0):

To Uninstall Simplenews you must delete Simplenews data first.
Go to /admin/config/services/simplenews/settings/uninstall then click "Delete Simplenews data".

[image]